# web.xml <filter-mapping> not working when using <servlet-name>

Tags: java, spring, servlet-filters, web.xml

I have a web.xml that has this in it:

```
 <filter>
    <description>CASRebroadcastFilter</description>
    <filter-name>CASRebroadcastFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>edu.utah.acs.tek.filters.CASSingleSignOutRebroadcast</filter-class>
</filter>

(... more CAS-filters)

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CASRebroadcastFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>        
</filter-mapping>

(... more CAS-filter-mappings and the rest of my web.xml...)
```

Environment: Spring 2.5, Glassfish 2.1

And this works as expected -- namely, the CASRebroadcastFilter intercepts and handles the appropriate calls and allows everything else to pass through.

But if I change my filter-mapping to this:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CASRebroadcastFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

It doesn't work.  And by "doesn't work" I mean exactly that:  everything passes through the CASRebroadcastFilter as if it's just not there and not a single error or other thing is output.

It's as if the `<servlet-name>` tag just doesn't work within the context of some aspect of my environment.

Has anyone else seen this or know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Could be due to the fact that you change the ordering of filters when you set it using servlet-name. The servlet container will run filters in the order they are configured in web.xml, first those using a url-pattern then those using servlet-name. So a filter using url-pattern is always executed before one using servlet-name.

So by changing it to using servlet-name you're effectively placing it after all filters using url-pattern.